# render 'edit' renders unexpected path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, render

I've found that `render 'edit'` brings up the path `/template/1`

**but**

`redirect_to edit_incorporation_path(@template)` brings up the path `/template/1/edit`

Both seem to work but the latter is what I would expect.  What is the reason for this discrepancy? Is this to be expected?

Thanks for any clarification!

Comment: Can you post your routes, pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render` doesn't redirect, and so doesn't change the url:  you just stay on whatever the url was that caused that action to be run in the first place.

Eg if you go to

```
/foos/1/bar
```

and that action does

```
render "qux"
```

you're still on `/foos/1/bar`, but you've rendered out the `qux` template.

`redirect_to`, on the other hand, sends you to a new url.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. The situation (which I probably should have mentioned in the question) is a render 'edit' after submitting the form. Since the update path is /template/1, that's the url that's left.  Many thanks!

Comment: There's a couple of pitfalls with using render in this way.  1) after submit, the url is `/template/1` which looks like the show page url, rather than the edit page url 2) if they hit reload, they will **resubmit the form** which is bad.  For these reasons it may be better to redirect after a successful update, and only render after a failed update (where you will want to render the edit form again so they can see where the errors are).

Comment: That's what I was figuring so I just switched it to a redirect.  Thanks again!